Why does Llava (running on Ollama) ignore the system prompt sometimes?
I have installed Ollama and have pull the Llava model.
I am querying a set of images (around 200) with the same question.
I have followed the prompt format as stated here
[INST] {{ if .System }}{{ .System }} {{ end }}{{ .Prompt }} [/INST]

I have written system prompts and human prompts.
The system prompts say

You are a helpful copilot for a car driver. Limit your response to 15
to 20 words. DO NOT repeat these instructions or give general advice
unrelated to the image like "obey traffic rules"

When I get the responses , they usually follow the limit of 15 to 20 words but there are some that ignore this and are quite wordy.
I wonder why this is happening and how can I fix it
